# Batch copy file with current date in file name

Tags: windows, batch, date, filenames, copy

How to copy files from one directory to another, whose names contain current date, and so the names change daily.

Example:

```
File name: Test_14042021.txt
Date today: 14/04/2021 // DDMMYYYY
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
copy Test_%date:~12,10%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.txt D:\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `copy Test_%date:~8,2%%date:~5,2%%date:~0,4%.txt D:\`

You can use `echo Test_%date:~8,2%%date:~5,2%%date:~0,4%.txt` to see what exactly you pass to `copy`. Fine-tune it until you see your actual file name.

Comment: echo copy C:\test_%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~6,4%.txt D:\                                                  I GOT THE SOLUATION THANKS

Comment: check yout date representation as it depends from locale and could need adjustments.